# OpenCv pytesseract for OCR

Tags: python, opencv

How to use opencv and pytesseract to extract text from image?

```
import cv2
```

import pytesseract
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

```
img = Image.open('test.jpg').convert('L')
img.show()
img.save('test','png')
img = cv2.imread('test.png',0)
edges = cv2.Canny(img,100,200)
#contour = cv2.findContours(edges, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
#print pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(edges))
print pytesseract.image_to_string(edges)
```

But this is giving error-

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "open.py", line 14, in 
    print pytesseract.image_to_string(edges)
  File "/home/sroy8091/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pytesseract/pytesseract.py", line 143, in image_to_string
    if len(image.split()) == 4:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you like to do some pre-processing using opencv (like you did some edge detection) and later on if you wantto extract text, you can use this command,

```
# All the imports and other stuffs goes here
img = cv2.imread('test.png',0)
edges = cv2.Canny(img,100,200)
img_new = Image.fromarray(edges)
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img_new, lang='eng')
print (text)
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use directly Opencv objects with tesseract methods.

Try:

```
from PIL import Image
from pytesseract import *

image_file = 'test.png'
print(pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(image_file)))
```